# Securing a Symfony2 application

Tags: security, symfony

i'm developing a Symfony2 app which involves users with hierarchical roles. Right now i can register, recover and login into the application without issues as i've implemented roles and users as described in Symfony2 docs.

At that point, i've developed some CRUD's in order to be able to manage objects in the application but in the current implementation i must check current user roles in order to let him or not run "selected" actions. I mean, in each controller i get security context, then user object and check permissions then sometimes i need to check the current user is the owner of the data - i.e if an user has clients i need to check url passed variables/id/whatever are owned/belongs the current user - and then deny access or not.

So, as far i'm used to and feeling comfortable developing the application as mentioned above i'm wondering is there is a better approach or a Symfony2 approach where i can manage roles and data in standard or more understanding way so future developers doesn't need to go through each if or check inside controllers+actions. I also would like to note i would be able to customize how data or objects are fetched or loaded so i can optimize sql's run in background.

Comment: No one knows? I thought about taking a look at Symfony ACL, although i don't know if they could give what i'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: SonataAdminBundle is great for CRUD, although there is quite a learning curve. As for security: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656759/best-practice-to-allow-access-to-owner-user-and-admins-only/16657093#16657093

Answer (score 0):

Symfony ACLs is exactly what you need. You can assign access rights (i.e. OWNER, EDIT, VIEW etc) to a single user or assign to all users with a certain role (or both).

If ACL is too complex for your needs, than an alternative approach would be to use a custom [Security Voter](http://kriswallsmith.net/post/15994931191/symfony2-security-voters).