# symfony2 / doctrine views? or equivalent

Tags: symfony, optimization, doctrine-orm

I have a question about **queries optimization** and **data "grouping"**

***Here's my setup :***

- I have a single application for multiple sites
- Items I display to my sites are stored in a single table (one item can be shown in different sites)

  - So I have joins between my "sites" table and "items" table

When a user authenticate in *site01* i'd like to present him *only the data for this site*.
I was wondering if there was a genius doctrine (or other) trick to make it transparent in my code:

***For example:***

- User authenticates for *site01*
- I set in my siteManager that it's *01*
- And all my entities of items (*for this session*) now refer to a *subset of my data* according to the JOIN with site01.

Like a **view** or something.

My concern is as much performance optimization than transparency in code.
Performance coming first.

***nb:*** the choice of using a single item table is not definite yet, it might be a bit to meta and/or conceptual to provide good performance.

Thank you in advance for any input on my question.

Comment: Ho, yeah, ACL had been considered but i don't think it helps with transparency nor performances.

Comment: This is a typical scenario for ACL, which can be user or group based. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656759/best-practice-to-allow-access-to-owner-user-and-admins-only/16657093#16657093